# Why does Pitch shifting make my audio sound weird?

Tags: sound-design

So I added a pitch shifter to my audio, making it a lot deeper. But when I listened to it the balance between the left and right channel weren't pan center anymore. The left and right was constantly changing, one moment the left would be louder, and then the right channel would be louder after that again. I'm new to adobe audition so I might be missing something basic, but I don't know why this is happening, or how I can change the voice channels to pan center.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1):

Pitch shifting left and right channel of a stereo signal separately is asking for trouble.  If you are starting from a mono channel, do the pitch shift first and the stereo imaging afterwards.  If you are starting from a stereo signal, try seeing whether you can find a stereo pitch shifter: two separate mono pitch shifters will do their splicing operations independently, leading to incoherent results.

Answer (score 0):

Panning shouldn't be a problem. Is the audio initially stereo or is it simply a mono track? Ensure that you start with a clean and blank project so that there is no possibility of any automation affecting the underlying track.

Furthermore to this, if you are working with audio in a stereo track, you need to make sure that you use a 'stereo' pitch shifter as opposed to two independent 'mono' pitch-shifters. If you use a 'stereo' pitch-shifter, then the effect will be linked across both the left and right channels and the effect of the pitch-shifting will be equal across each channel. Using a mono pitch-shifter will pitch-shift each track independently and will cause shifting of amplitude, phase and other elements which will likely result in image-shifting.

Always use a linked stereo effect when working with stereo tracks, as opposed to dual-mono tracks.